# How to use Razor Class Library from a Webforms Web Application Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webforms, asp.net-core-2.1

As part of migration process I would like to use [Razor Class Library](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/03/01/asp-net-core-2-1-razor-ui-in-class-libraries/) in a WebForms project. Is it possible?

**Testing scenario**

A solution with three projects (created by Visual Studion 2017 15.7.2):

- Project *CoreLibraryTest*: Razor Class Library (Core 2.1, Target Framework 4.7.1)
- Project *RazorPages*: ASP.Net Core Web Application with Razor Pages (Core 2.1, Target Framework 4.7.1)
- Project *WebForms*: ASP.Net Web Application (.NET Framework) with MVC and Webforms (Target Framework 4.7.1)

In CoreLibraryTest I have Areas/MyFeature/Page1.cshtml (structure created by VS2017). To Page1 body I add some text (e.g. Hello). When I add the reference to *CoreLibraryTest* to  *RazorPages*, run *RazorPages* and add `/MyFeature/Page1` to the browser address bar it displyas the page. The same process for *WebForms* will result in 404 page not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution. Referencing Razor Class Library from a Webforms Web Application Project is not possible.

Reference:

[Razor Class Library is not routed properly when referenced from a WebForms project](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/3196)